# Anime with a stone creature cared for by a little girl

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw this in a reel that I forgot to save. The theme of the reel was "villains are made not born" and it showed a stone creature? I think it was stone. The creature was sort of tied or chained and alone and a little girl approached it and fed it I think. it grew big enough and had one flower growing from its shoulder I think. But then the villagers kill the girl in front of the creature and it goes into rage mode.
That's all I saw, but I really would be happy if someone can identify this based on my description.

Comment: When did you see this? And do you recall the hair colour of the girl?

Comment: I saw the insta reel about 5 months ago. and I think it was normal hair color. like black or brown

Comment: Makes me think a bit of "Somali and the Forest Spirit", but the golem looks more metallic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[The Last Summoner](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt19893526/)*.

> A talented young cook's encounter with a hungry girl who popped up in
> his kitchen changes his ordinary life forever. Dora, a summoned spirit
> and a truly cute goddess, now calls him master. However, he is not
> interested at all and tries everything he could to get away from the
> ghostly figure. As fate would have it, when he becomes a summoner by
> accident, he realizes there is no turning back in life

The incident you're describing matches the video below very closely. Man (Moduo) with flower on his shoulder watches his friend (a young girl) being killed by villagers.

> 

Comment: thank you YES! you found the actual video too. thank you thank you

Comment: @Danahi82 - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)